# How to get user input for Ajax.ActionLink call for action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I want to use ajax action link to save one field with no change for view.

Here is my view(it is a strongly-typed view bound to type Model):

```
   <%= Html.TextBox("myComment", Model.MyComment)%>
   <%= Ajax.ActionLink("SAVE", "SaveComment", "Home",
       Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"})
   %>
```

Here is my Action for ajax actionlink in controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public void SaveComment(Model model)
{
    MyRepository repository = new MyRepository();
    Model mod = repository.GetModel(model.ID);
    mod.MyComment = model.MyComment;

    try
    {
        repository.Save();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }          
}
```

The problem is: I can't get the user input in textbox for Mycomment in action method. Whatever user input in browser for Mycomment, when click on Ajax ActionLink SAVE, then I check the value from param model for Mycomment, there is nothing changed for MyComment.

Confused is: Model should be bound to view in bi-way. but for this case, it seems not.
Then I changed the Ajax.ActionLink call to:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("SAVE", "SaveComment", "Home",
       new {commentinput =Model.MyComment, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

then changed action method signature as:

```
public void SaveComment(string commentinput)
```

I still can't get the user input.

How to get the user input in controller action method?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK Ajax.ActionLink doesn't allow you to easily get form values and post them with AJAX. There are some [workarounds](http://www.aspnetpro.com/articles/2009/06/asp200906de_f/asp200906de_f.asp) which seem quite hackish (looking at the last paragraph *Adapting the URL Dynamically* makes me cry).

Here's the jQuery way (I prefer it if compared to MS Ajax):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("myComment", Model.MyComment) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("SAVE", "SaveComment", "Home", new { id = "saveComment" }) %>
```

And then unobtrusively attach a click event handler to the anchor:

```
$(function() {
    $('a#saveComment').click(function(evt) {
        $.ajax({
            url : this.href,
            data: {
                // Assuming your model has a property called MyComment
                myComment: $('#myComment').val()
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                // Comment saved successfully
            }
        });
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. but my view is a table, <%= Html.TextBox("myComment", Model.MyComment)%> is for each row in the table.