# ActionLink to submit Model value

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I want my Ajax.ActionLink to pass a viewModel property to action.

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Searchtext { get; set; }
    }
```

My .cshtml

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Bottom3", "Bottom3",new { name = Model.Searchtext}, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "pointsDiv"
})

 using(Html.BeginForm("Bottom3", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
     {
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Searchtext)
         <button type="submit">Search</button>
     }
    <div id="pointsDiv"></div>
}
```

My Controller action:

```
public PartialViewResult Bottom3(string name)
        {
            var model = db.XLBDataPoints.OrderBy(x => x.DataPointID).Take(3).ToList();

            return PartialView("Partial1", model);
        }
```

But the name parameter passed to the action is always null. How do I solve this?

Comment: You have 2 ways to post a value in your view: the ActionLink and the Form. The VALUE in the form, is updated if you write something... but the link has the original value (empty). You can test it putting a default value in the Searchtext property.

Comment: Check this in order to post the entered value: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1148468/7720

Comment: @Romias: Could you please elaborate your answer? I understand from your comment that there are 2 ways to solve this, but could you please brief it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code... you have 2 different ways of posting to the server: the link and the form button.

The problem is that the ActionLink has no way to get the value from the input in client side... just the original value.

If you press the Search button, you will see a value posted.

Now, you can use some jQuery to modify a standard ActionLink (not the Ajax.ActionLink): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1148468/7720

Or... you can transform your Form in order to do a Ajax post instead of a normal one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051612/7720

Comment: In the second link you posted, there is no action link, he has turned it into a submit button.How do I retain my action link. I dont want the jquery way of doing it , as my Action link has to post Model parameters as well, I dont want jQuery to post ViewModel parameter to action.

Comment: An ActionLink helper just creates an anchor during the creation of the view. So, at this time you can't get the values the user enters. For that you need javascript. So, in your case is better to use the form. The other values you want to post, can be placed as Hidden inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a model of mine like so.  I ONLY supported the HttpPost method.  So add the HttpMethod="POST" to your Ajax.ActionLink

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Accounts(ParametricAccountsModel model)
    {
        if (model.Accounts == null)
        {
            GetAccountsForModel(model);
        }
        if (model.AccountIds == null)
        {
            model.AccountIds = new List<int>();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

On the razor view

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Add Account to Order", "Accounts", "Parametric", null,
        new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "...", HttpMethod = "POST" },
        new { @id = "AddParametricAccountLink" })
```

The model has a list of selected account ids.  So in javascript, I modified the href of the action link dynamically.

```
function UpdateParametricAccountAction() {
    var originalLink = '/TradeNCashMgmt/Parametric/Accounts';
    var append = '';
    var numberOfRows = $('#ParametricAccounts').find('.parametric-account-  row').size();
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            append += '&';
        }
        else {
            append = '?';
        }
        var idValue = $('#NotionalTransactionsAccountId_' + i).val();
        append += 'AccountIds%5B' + i + '%5D=' + idValue;
    }

    $('#AddParametricAccountLink').attr('href', originalLink + append);
}
```

Since the model binder looks for parameter names in the query string and form submission, it will pick up values using the href. So I posted a model object using the querystring on my Ajax.ActionLink.  Not the cleanest method, but it works.