# How to extract the value from a radio button and pass it to action via ajax.actionlink in mvc4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a list of questions and options and the options are displayed as radiobuttons in the view. I have the previous and next action methods which can be accessed by the Ajax.ActionLink() s , While sending , I want to extract the value of the radiobutton that is selected. Can anybody suggest a nice implementation please?

My View :

```
<div class="techquestions" id="techquestiondetail">
                    <div>
                        <h4>Q.</h4><h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => TechQ.Question)</h5><br />
                        <div>Options:</div><br />
                        <div class="tech_answer_radiobutton" id="tech_radiobuttongroup">
                            @Html.RadioButton("OptionSelected", TechQ.OptionA)<span> @TechQ.OptionA.ToString()</span>
                            @Html.RadioButton("OptionSelected", TechQ.OptionB)<span> @TechQ.OptionB.ToString()</span>
                            @Html.RadioButton("OptionSelected", TechQ.OptionC)<span> @TechQ.OptionC</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Previous", "Previous", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"]) }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "parti", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Next", "Next", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"])  }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "parti", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Next(int id, string answer) //the optionselected should come here
{

}
```

can we generate the ajax.actionlink's url like this : `AwesomeController/DoSomething?foo=foo1&bar=bar1?`

Comment: [This SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353492/actionlink-to-submit-model-value) should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Ajax.ActionLink()`. Use jquery functions instead (asn save youself the unnecessary extra overhead of including `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js`). Modify the html for the links to

```
<a href="#" id="previous">Previous</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

and add the following script

```
var id = '@Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"])'
var target = $('#parti');
$('#previous').click(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("Previous")';
  var answer = $('#OptionSelected').val();
  target.load(url, { id: id, answer: answer });
}
$('#next').click(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("Next")';
  var answer = $('#OptionSelected').val();
  target.load(url, { id: id, answer: answer });
}
```